# Apache/PHP using 100% CPU while trying to free cache space

Tags: php, apache, caching, cpu-usage, lockup

I created a script for use with my website that is supposed to erase the oldest entry in cache when a new item needs to be cached. My website is very large with 500,000 photos on it and the cache space is set to 2 GB.

These functions are what cause the trouble:

```
function cache_tofile($fullf, $c)
{
    error_reporting(0);
    if(strpos($fullf, "/") === FALSE)
    {
        $fullf = "./".$fullf;
    }
    $lp = strrpos($fullf, "/");
    $fp = substr($fullf, $lp + 1);
    $dp = substr($fullf, 0, $lp);
    $sz = strlen($c);
    cache_space_make($sz);
    mkdir($dp, 0755, true);
    cache_space_make($sz);
    if(!file_exists($fullf))
    {
        $h = @fopen($fullf, "w");
        if(flock($h, LOCK_EX))
        {
            ftruncate($h, 0);
            rewind($h);
            $tmo = 1000;
            $cc = 1;
            $i = fputs($h, $c);
            while($i < strlen($c) || $tmo-- > 1)
            {
                $c = substr($c, $i);
                $i = fwrite($h, $c);
            }
            flock($h, LOCK_UN);
            fclose($h);
        }
    }
    error_reporting(7);
}

function cache_space_make($sz)
{
    $ct = 0;
    $cf = cachefolder();
    clearstatcache();
    $fi = shell_exec("df -i ".$cf." | tail -1 | awk -F\" \" '{print \$4}'");
    if($fi < 1)
    {
        return;
    }
    if(($old = disk_free_space($cf)) === false)
    {
        return;
    }
    while($old < $sz)
    {
        $ct++;
        if($ct > 10000)
        {
            error_log("Deleted over 10,000 files. Is disk screwed up?");
            break;
        }
        $fi = shell_exec("rm \$(find ".$cf."cache -type f -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort | head -1 | awk -F\" \" '{print \$2}');");
        clearstatcache();
        $old = disk_free_space($cf);
    }
}
```

`cachefolder()` is a function that returns the correct folder name with a `/` appended to it.

When the functions are executed, the CPU usage for apache is between 95% and 100% and other services on the server are extremely slow to access during that time. I also noticed in whm that cache disk usage is at 100% and refuses to drop until I clear the cache. I was expecting more like maybe 90ish%.

What I am trying to do with the cache_tofile function is attempt to free disk space in order to create a folder then free disk space to make the cache file. The cache_space_make function takes one parameter representing the amount of disk space to free up.

In that function I use system calls to try to find the oldest file in the directory tree of the entire cache and I was unable to find native php functions to do so.

The cache file format is as follows:

```
/cacherootfolder/requestedurl
```

For example, if one requests http://www.example.com/abc/def then from both functions, the folder that is supposed to be created is abc and the file is then def so the entire file in the system will be:

```
/cacherootfolder/abc/def
```

If one requests http://www.example.com/111/222 then the folder 111 is created and the file 222 will be created

```
/cacherootfolder/111/222
```

Each file in both cases contain the same content as what the user requests based on the url. (example: /cacherootfolder/111/222 contains the same content as what one would see when viewing source from http://www.example.com/111/222)

The intent of the caching system is to deliver all web pages at optimal speed.

My question then is how do I prevent the system from trying to lockup when the cache is full. Is there better code I can use than what I provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by replacing the `||` in your code by `&&`, which was most likely the intention.
Currently, the loop will **always** run **at least 1000 times** - I very much hope the intention was to **stop trying** after 1000 times.

Also, drop the `ftruncate` and `rewind`.
From the [PHP Manual on `fopen`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) (emphasis mine):

> 'w'       Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file **and truncate the
>
>               file to zero length**. If the  file does not exist, attempt to create it.

So your `truncate` is redundant, as is your `rewind`.

Next, review your `shell_exec`'s.
The one outside the loop doesn't seem too much of a bottleneck to me, but the one **inside** the loop...
Let's say you have 1'000'000 files in that cache folder.
`find` will happily list all of them for you, no matter how long it takes.
Then you sort that list.
And then **you flush 999'999 entries of that list down the toilet**, and only keep the first one.
Then you do some stuff with `awk` that I don't really care about, and then you delete the file.
On the next iteration, you'll only have to go through 999'999 files, of which you **discard only 999'998**.
See where I'm going?
I consider calling shell scripts out of pure convenience bad practice anyway, but if you do it, do it as efficiently as possible, at least!
Do one `shell_exec` without `head -1`, store the resulting list in a variable, and iterate over it.
Although it might be better to abandon `shell_exec` altogether and instead program the corresponding routines in PHP (one could argue that `find` and `rm` are machine code, and therefore faster than code written in PHP to do the same task, but there sure is *a lot* of overhead for all that IO redirection).

Please do all that, and then see how bad it still performs.
If the results are still unacceptable, I suggest you put in some code to measure the time certain parts of those functions require (tip: [`microtime(true)`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php)) or use a profiler, like [XDebug](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler), to see where exactly most of your time is spent.

Also, why did you turn off error reporting for that block? Looks more than suspicious to me.

And as a little bonus, you can get rid of `$cc` since you're not using it anywhere.

Comment: I used `||` because its a loop to make sure data is written because sometimes fwrite may not return all the bytes written. The problem I have is that this code could be executed by multiple users at once and if I don't flush the cache always then the wrong file might be removed? Perhaps I need a special function to tell the system that this code can only be executed by one user.

Comment: But... `||` still means "at least 1000 times"... and yes, you very much should make sure that script only runs one at a time. Such a script should run as a cronjob rather than from an HTTP request anyway, just to make sure the max execution time doesn't pull the plug.

Comment: Ok due to processing times, I'll be better off ditching the cache on low space considering the cache only improves the TTFB of the page by maybe 100ms